# Will Kresh the Bloodbraided survive damage through his ability in a boardwide damage scenario?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Kresh the Bloodbraided](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=244672) is on the battlefield with another creature, let's say a 1/1.

Kresh has the following ability:

> Whenever another creature dies, you may put X +1/+1 counters on Kresh the Bloodbraided, where X is that creature's power.

The opponent deals 5 damage to both of them, which should kill them both. Will Kresh's ability trigger to make him a 6/6 and save him from being killed by the 5 damage?

Comment: For clarity, I would edit the question to mention the card that is dealing the 5 damage. Also, Kresh is a 3/3, so putting a +1/+1 counter on Kresh would not make him a 6/6. Can we assume that Kresh already has a couple of counters on him?

Answer (score 6):

If Kresh is a 5/5 when the damage is dealt,  he will die when the damage resolves because he will have 5 damage marked on him the next time state-based actions are checked, causing him to go to the graveyard. The check will occur before the triggered ability resolves, so he'll never have the chance to add the +1/+1 counter.

Comment: Apologies for the 5/5 mistake, not sure how that number stuck in my head instead of 3/3.
So does that mean that his ability won't trigger for the death of the other creature? Is this the case for all simultanous death triggers? For example Omnath + elemental creature dying at the same time causing Omnath to not fire for 3?

Comment: @Wooya Kresh's ability *will* trigger, but he will be dead when triggered ability resolves. Once he is dead, the counters cannot be placed on him. Some similarly worded abilities can work better because their effects don't inherently rely on the original creature still existing.

Comment: @wooya I realized it was a mistake, but the answer is the same and Kresh being a 5/5 isn't really that uncommon so no worries.

Comment: @wooya In the case of Omnath, all the triggers happen when he dies based on what he "sees" on the board. Spell damage happens at the same time for all affected creatures, so Omnath sees himself die and sees the elemental die, resulting in 2 triggers. If Omnath is alone, he still sees himself die, so only 1 trigger. The key takeaway here is that all damage happens at once for a Pyroclasm type spell where mass damage is dealt, so triggers that are the result of that damage occur after the spell resolves.